# El codigo javascript no envia al controlador

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy realizando una aplicación web en C# ASP.NET MVC5, necesito en la vista validar un dropdownlist que no este vacio, y cuando este lleno enviar los datos al controlador.

**JavaScript**

```
function Validar() {
    var pais_id = document.getElementById("id_pais ").selectedIndex;
    if (pais_id == 0) {
        document.getElementById("id_pais ").focus();
        alert('[ERROR] El campo Test es requerido.');
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
       document.registros.action = @Url.Action("Index", "Registros");
      document.registros.submit();  
    }
}
```

**la vista**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "registros", id = "registros", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.pais)
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("id_stb", null, "Seleccione un Pais")

        </div>
        @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
        {
        @ViewBag.Message
        }
    </div>
```

Cuando pruebo solamente el `alert` si funciona, pero cuando le añado la parte del `submit`, ya no funciona el método, ni siquiera el `alert`. Me imagino que tenga mal puesto el URL al controlador.
Soy nueva en esto de C# y asp.net, gracias de antemano.

Comment: La url debes encerrarla entre comillas: `document.registros.action = '@Url.Action("Index", "Registros")';`

Comment: @AsierVillanueva gracias, a veces las cosas más sencillas las pasamos por alto, funciono bien